# Excel VBA + Userform Checkboxes :: Hide/Unhide columns using Form Checkboxes

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am hoping someone will be able to assist me in the issue I am having. Let me start by saying I am not the best with VBA, I'm new to it.

***ISSUE***

I am trying to create a simple userform with checkboxes (13 Checkboxes) which will allow the user to hide/unhide columns they choose. I have **70** columns from S to BR. I know, this may sound like a lot, but it is needed. I have **13 Periods** and **each** **period has 4 columns** I.E. **Period 1 has columns **S:V**.**

What I cannot get it to do is, get the checkboxes on the userform to hide/unhide the periods selected by the user. The code I have tried. I followed many tutorials and cannot get it to work what so ever. I'm not sure if this makes sense, But I have added in all the code I have in hopes for it to work.

I have also added in images of the columns so that you can get a better understanding... I hope

I hope someone can assist me in this matter as it's vital I get this working. Thank you very much in advance.

[***IMAGE HERE (BEST OPEN IN NEW TAB)*** These columns go all the way up to PERIOD 13 or WEEK 52](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8lET.png)

```
  Sub hideCol(C As Integer)
    If Controls("CheckBox" & C ) = True Then
        Columns(C).Hidden = True
    Else
        Columns(C).Hidden = False
    End If
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
End Sub 

 Private Sub CheckBox1_Clickl()
    Dim C As Integer
    C = (19, 20, 21, 22)
    Call hideCol(C)
End Sub

 Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    Dim C As Integer
    C = (23, 24, 25, 26)
    Call hideCol(C)
End Sub

 Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()
    Dim C As Integer
    C = (27, 28, 29, 30)
    Call hideCol(C)
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox4_Click()
    Dim C As Integer
    C = (31, 32, 33, 34)
    Call hideCol(C)
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox5_Click()
    Dim C As Integer
    C = (35, 36, 37, 38)
    Call hideCol(C)
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox6_Click()
    Dim C As Integer
    C = (39, 40, 41, 42)
    Call hideCol(C)
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox7_Click()
    Dim C As Integer
    C = (43, 44, 45, 46)
    Call hideCol(C)
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox8_Click()
    Dim C As Integer
    C = (47, 48, 49, 50)
    Call hideCol(C)
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox9_Click()
    Dim C As Integer
    C = (51, 52, 53, 54)
    Call hideCol(C)
End Sub

 Private Sub CheckBox10_Click()
    Dim C As Integer
    C = (55, 56, 57, 58)
    Call hideCol(C)
End Sub

 Private Sub CheckBox11_Click()
    Dim C As Integer
    C = (59, 60, 61, 62)
    Call hideCol(C)
End Sub

 Private Sub CheckBox12_Click()
    Dim C As Integer
    C = (63, 64, 65, 66)
    Call hideCol(C)
End Sub

 Private Sub CheckBox13_Click()
    Dim C As Integer
    C = (67, 68, 69, 70)
    Call hideCol(C)
End Sub

 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize ()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 19 to 70
        Controls("CheckBox" & i).caption = Cells(5, i)
        If Columns(i).Hidden = True Then
            Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value = True
        End If
        Next i
    End Sub 
 'This is supposed to get the name of the column I.e Period 1, period 2, period 3 and title it in the checkboxes accordingly. Not working though :( :( :( :(
```

---

### ***ADDITION***

***Whenever I try running this. I get " Run-Time Error '-2147024808 (80070057)':
Could not find the specified object.***

---

Again, thank you very much for any help provided. I've been trying to get this working for a few days now and cannot figure it out. It wouldn't surprise me if all the code is completely wrong :/.

Comment: You need to define where your controls are in your hideCol sub. e.g. `UserForm1.Controls("CheckBox" & C) = True`. I'm having a look into the rest now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can achieve your goal by changing the code.

Rather than setting the columns to variable C and then calling a subroutine to hide the columns set to C, I've written the `CheckBox_click` event to hide/unhide the columns.

For example, I've assigned this code to `CheckBox1` on `UserForm1`;

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        Sheets(1).Columns("D:G").Hidden = True
    ElseIf Me.CheckBox1.Value = False Then
        Sheets(1).Columns("D:G").Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Basically this is saying, each time `CheckBox1` on `UserForm1` is clicked, determine if the value of the checkbox is now `True` or `False`. If `True`, hide the columns D, E, F and G, otherwise if `False`, unhide the columns.

If this is what you're looking for, simply add the code to each CheckBox_click event and change the name of your control to suit e.g. `CheckBox2`, `CheckBox3` etc).

### To remember your selections in the UserForm

When the workbook is closed or the `UserForm` is unloaded from memory, your selections are 'forgotten'. **But** your columns only hide/unhide when the `CheckBox` is clicked. This means when subsequently the Workbook is opened and/or the UserForm is loaded, all the CheckBoxes will show their value at initialization (False by default).

> **Note:** When the userform is unloaded from memory, all variables are forgotten so we can't use VBA to remember our selections for next
>   time.

So, one way we can 'remember' our selections has the following 3 steps:

1. Put an ActiveX `CheckBox` on our Spreadsheet somewhere out of the way (We'll use sheet1 as the example).
2. In the `CheckBox_click` code, add a new line in our code to assign the matching value from our userform checkbox to our Worksheet `CheckBox`.
3. In the `UserForm_Initialization` code, set the value of our Worksheet `CheckBox` to our `UserForm` `CheckBox`.

   ### Step 1

   In your WorkBook, with the relevant sheet selected go to the 'Developer Tab', click 'Insert' and choose the CheckBox.

[image: Visual of where to find ActiveX controls to insert onto a sheet.]

Then 'draw' the `CheckBox` onto your sheet wherever you want to put it (the same way you would in the VBE for you `UserForm`.

### Step 2

Add the following lines of code to the `CheckBox_click` code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        Sheets(1).Columns("D:G").Hidden = True
        Sheet1.CheckBox1.Value = True '<~~ HERE
    ElseIf Me.CheckBox1.Value = False Then
        Sheets(1).Columns("D:G").Hidden = False
        Sheet1.CheckBox1.Value = False '<~~ AND HERE
    End If
End Sub
```

### Step 3

On our `Userform1` code, enter the following:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.CheckBox1.Value = Sheet1.CheckBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Welll uhm.... I now officially feel 100% newbie. As far as I can see this work. Thank you very much for you help. I appreciate it a lot. I spend two days on it and you do it in less than an hour. :D

Comment: I forgot to ask sorry. Is there a way for me to make the spreadsheet memorise which state it is in as in, whether or not the columns are hidden or shown. When I close it down and open the spreadhseet. The checkboxes show as them being shown but they're actually not. Thanks

Comment: @DougLogan When you say "...make the spreadsheet memorise which state it is in as in, whether or not the columns are hidden or shown." do you mean make the userform remember if the checkbox is checked or not?

Comment: Yes sorry, that is what I mean. Thanks

Comment: @DougLogan I've edited my answer to explain how this could be achieved. It's important to understand that when the workbook is closed, all values and variables are lost as the UserForm is unloaded from memory (and of course, memory is where the values and variables are stored). My edit explains a way to mirror the checkbox values onto checkboxes on the worksheet which are remembered as part of the data stored on the sheet (not stored in memory) and to set your userform checkboxes to the worksheet checkbox value when you initialize the userform.

Comment: Ok, So I followed the step-by-step guide as per your specification, but for some unknown reason I get an error saying ***Compile Error: Method or data member not found*** from what I understand, I'm doing it all as per the step-by-step guide.

Comment: I added in a screenshot. won't display but it's in there under "Error"

Comment: @DougLogan off the top of my head, make sure all references are consistant with your Workbook. E.g. for  `Sheet1.CheckBox1.Value = True` ensure the Checkbox is named 'CheckBox1' and the sheet is named 'sheet1' etc.

Comment: @DougLogan do not edit an answer if you want to comment on it.

Comment: I've taken a thorough look through it, all appears to be fine with naming's etc. No idea what's causing it. Could be something interfering with the code? if that's even possible.

Comment: @douglogan hmmm if you haven't already, include `Option Explicit`at the top of your code window. This helps identify spelling mistakes and the like. Do you know what line the compile error occurs?

Comment: @DougLogan it worked fine for me with a new Userform. Perhaps open a new workbook to test this on that way we can isolate if  this code works or not for you. Then add any other code you're using bit by bit and see if any errors occur. As it works for me I can only assume you have a simple spelling mistake or an incorrect object name *OR* there is an error in another part of your code.

Comment: The errors are saying to be happening on lines 14, 17 and 118

Comment: Been trying to figure all this time woth what's causing the errors and I have failed. Everything seems to be correct, to me at least lol

Comment: I'd suggest checking again that all of your objects are using the correct names in your code. I tested putting an incorrect name in for the sheet checkbox (Mine is named `CheckBox1` so I tested with `CheckBox11`) and got the same error. Remember the '(Name)' in the VBE is what you reference in your code, not the 'Caption' (which is what you see on the sheet). To check these details for the sheet Checkbox, click design mode and right click the object > properties. At work imgur is blocked so I can't attach any images sorry.

Comment: @Samuel So in the end I managed to get the code working, I had to rename the sheet, and adjust the code slightly instead of  ` Sheet1.CheckBox1.Value = True ` I had to change it to ` Sheets("CheckBoxVal").P1CheckBoxConf.Value = True `

Comment: Ok so that worked, but after further testing, it still doesn't seem to be saving the settings. I wanted it so that it would not only save which columns are shown and hidden but also leave the checkbox in it's state of which it was closed I.E If check box is checked, then check box will stay checked upon opening. But it doesn't seem to do that. They all end up unchecked when I reopen the spreadsheet.

Comment: Along with if the userform is closed, the value of the checkbox should stay the same also... which is doesn't. Tried a few things, but doesn't work lol I'm a literal newbie

Comment: @douglogan did you correct your object names in the `UserForm_Initialize` Private Sub? The logic of my answer for 'remembering' the `UserForm` `CheckBox.Value` is when the value is changed on the userform, it updates a `CheckBox` control on the sheet to match the userform. As discussed above, when the `UserForm` is unloaded for any reason your userform checkbox values are forgotten but the checkboxes on the sheet are not so on the userform initalize event, we assign the sheet checkbox values to the userform checkboxes.

Comment: @SamuelEverson Yes, I corrected all names. But for some reason, it doesn't seem to be saving if the value of the check box is checked or unchecked. If I tick it then close the spreadsheet or userform itself, It appears Unchecked again but the column with stay hidden/shown. I then have to tick it then unyick it to unhide the column. It's weird. No clue if this makes sense.

Checkbox Ticked = Hidden
Checkbox Un-Ticked = Unhidden

Comment: @Douglogan so to confirm, you have your checkboxes on your userform AND your checkboxes on your spreadsheet, correct?

Comment: @douglogan and i'm confident you've followed the code in 'step 2' of my answer where **for example** when you click checkbox1 on the userform it updates the value of checkbox1 on the sheet?

Comment: @SamuelEverson I followed step 2 yes. Exactly what you said down to a T.

Comment: @douglogan hmmmm... can you confirm that when you click a checkbox on the userform, the value updates on the corresponding checkbox on the sheet?

Comment: @SamuelEverson Yes I can also confirm this. I triple checked that worked.

Comment: @douglogan i'm going to test 1 last thing but need to switch from.my phone to pc. I'l check back with you in a few moments.

Comment: @SamuelEverson Alright not a problem thanks. If need be, I can always send the sheet over excluding any data on it. There may be a chance I missed something. Who knows lol

Comment: @DougLogan I was going to try and avoid getting a copy of your sheet (of course with no data on it), but without seeing your actual code, I don't think I can offer any more help! I was checking to see if I could make a little debug tool to help clarify something but It didn't really offer any new information. Let me know how you can share your sheet and we'll go from there.

Comment: @SamuelEverson I will upload the file to my Google drive and shall forward you the link. I hope this is sufficient enough

Comment: @douglogan no problems. Just keep in mind anyone could potentially access the file if you share it here 

Comment: Is there anyway, I can privately send you the link where we can discuss the matter, or will I need to post the link here?

Comment: @douglogan, if you send it via email to a gmail account, does that work?

Comment: Yes that works. If you wish to email me via dougieklogan@gmail.com then I will send you the link. That way you are not disclosing your email address. I have one of many so it's not a problem with me.